# Jump through stack frames using ptrace

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, ptrace

I am trying to jump through the stack frames of a process using ptrace on x86_64. As per my understanding each RBP holds the address of the RBP of the previous frame and I am trying to follow the same in the code. The sequence of calls is:

```
static int pointer_size = sizeof(void*);
rbp_val = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, pid, RBP * pointer_size, 0);
prev_rbp = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, rbp_val, 0);
```

Often I get rbp_val as 0x4 and the second call to ptrace fails with errno 5 (Input/output error).
What am I missing?

Comment: `RBP` doesn't hold the frame pointer. In *some* x86-64 programs (those compiled without `-fomit-frame-pointer`), the **register** `%rbp` holds the frame pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain what should be the correct way to jump through the stack frames?

Comment: This is *very* platform dependent. First of, you really can't stacktrace a running program. So, you have to halt its execution (SIGNAL, whatever), then you need to get the value of `%rbp` of a different process, which is *horribly* platform dependent. I think on linux you need to get a `context*` from the OS, but that sounds... interesting.

Comment: Thanks again! I am going through the discussion in the the following thread as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625352/x86-64-calling-conventions-and-stack-frames